# Flutter Back Navigation and Bloc Data

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have this flow

```
screen1->screen2(A)->screen2(B)
```

What happens is from screen1 it goes to detail screen2 (with data set A), then within this screen there is a button that will call again screen2 with another set of data (data set B)

So when I want to go back this is where the data still showing data B

```
screen2(B)->screen2(B)->screen1
```

What I expect is

```
screen2(B)->screen2(A)->screen1
```

Is this something to do with BloC BehaviorSubject pattern? I try PublishSubject but also the same result.

Comment: Are you using `Navigator.push` method? How are going from screen2(A)->screen2(B) from Code Side .?

Comment: Yes using push method. It's like subcontent hierarchy so I'm using the same screen but load different data based on the id user tap like this `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('screen2/catId=${categoryId}');`

Answer (score 0):

I would change your navigation a bit, so that you use

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('screen2', arguments: {'categoryId': categoryId});
```

And your screen2 Widget on build gets the specified categoryId from the arguments

`Map args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;`

gets its details and shows it or does whatever. Then, when you press device back button it must work as expected.